# Sending attachment from file input in form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Hello I have a simple form which collect files. What I mean is that user should be able to put a file into the field and then by submitting the form mail should be sent to the address which is predefined and hardcoded.

here is my form:

```
<form action='/?page=admin-send' method='post' class='asholder' enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n";
    <input type='file' name='file' id ='file'/><button name='accept' value='".$ssl->id."' type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

And now using `Php` I want to collect this file and put it into email attachment.

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $filename = basename($file);
            $file_size = filesize($file);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file))); 
            $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
            $msg = "Hello, this is email with attachment!";

            $mail = new HTMLMail();
            $mail->from = 'DO NOT REPLY';
            $mail->to = 'tstmail@testhost.com';
            $mail->subject = 'admin warrning';
            $mail->importance = 'Low';
            $mail->body = "<P><FONT SIZE=2 FACE=\"Tahoma\">$msg</FONT></P>";
            $mail->headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n"
              ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
              ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n"
              ."This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n" 
              ."--".$uid."\r\n"
              ."Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"
              ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
              ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n"
              .$content."\r\n\r\n"
              ."--".$uid."--"; 

            $mail->send();
```

And here is the scenario I have problem with:
I put file with name of `xyz.pdf` which is some document the most important thing is that this document is all right. When I submit my form I am getting the email. Email has attachment which name is `xyz.pdf` but when I am trying to open this file I am getting the message that the file is borken.

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **have done** the same kind of task, i expect that my answer will help you for sure.

---

You are letting user **1.** upload a file **>** **2.** process it at your server side using PHP **>** **3.** and them you are using **HTML mail class** to send your mail.

The problem is in **third step**. If the class does not provide you with sufficient function of mail, then it is not worth using. **Writing mail HEADERS by yourself** poses a lot of complexity and we as a developer should not go that inside.
I recommend you to use **PHPMailer 5.1.2**, to do this job. This is very simple and is of not more than 80KB (the core files, excluding demos, guides). 
With this you can attach multiple files of any mime type(pdf, jpeg, doc etc.) without worrying about headers. This is very simple and i have tested , the attachments are readable at the mailbox.
 
If you download complete package with demos, you will see how easy it is to implement with PHP.
PHPMailer is the best free php class to send mails on the net(i think) with no bugs.
I haven't used HTML Mail class what you are using, so don't know whether it has functions for attaching files. But writing mail headers is not good. If you are using it by your wish after knowing all this, then i am sorry for posting this answer.

Comment: I forgot one thing, if you go for downloading PHPMailer, then download it from sourceforge.com, it also consists various demos to make it's use clear.

Comment: Official PHPMailer's github README says : **Please *DON'T* use the SourceForge or Google Code projects any more.**

Comment: @jave.web - I'd used that about 6 months ago. I don't remember the source. Please google it.. you will find for sure. That'll work. Try!

Comment: dont be missunderstood - it was just a reaction to your recommendation "download it from sourceforge"... - there surely is the SourceForge version, but the actual "offical" developing and releases are on GitHub - actual version is more recommended isnt it ? ;)